# Is docker must run under linux 64bits?

Tags: docker

I heard that docker must run under 64bit linux. Is it correct? 
We will implement a linux with ARM core - 32bits. Is the docker can run under this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now docker only supports amd64 architecture. According to this post, docker developers will eventually provide support for other architectures,

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/136.

Answer (score 0):

> Docker requires a 64-bit installation regardless of your Ubuntu version.

https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/

https://docs.docker.com/installation/